# VirtualBox Shared Folder encoding issue

Tags: virtualbox, mount, encoding

I'm using Ubuntu in Virtualbox and have a shared folder mounted to Virtualbox which i'm accessing inside Ubuntu.

The problem is, that when i'm editing and saving some files from shared folder in Windows it's getting some strange symbols at the end of edited file.

There must be some encoding issues. Doesn't Virtualbox automatically converts files to Unix standards?

To fix that, i have to re-mount shared folder inside Ubuntu each time i'm editing some file.

Any solution to avoid re-mounting each time I edit?

I'm mounting like that:

```
mount -t vboxsf SVN /opt/htdocs/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much flexing:

> The fix is to include:
>
> EnableSendfile Off

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=24905&p=111648&hilit=Shared+Folder+mount+javascript#p111648

http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/development